# Анимация как в Windows 8

Tags: css3, jquery

Подскажите как сделать анимацию как в винде 8: при нажатии на плитку она развопачивается на весь экран и одновременно поворачивается на 180, открывая приложение

Answer (score 2):

относительно несложно: css-transitions.
transform: rotate будет ключевым свойством.

Comment: Добавлю чуть-чуть: это, похоже, полностью готовое решение (сам не использовал) - http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/windows8-animations/